# Featherlight - how to open lightbox with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, modal-dialog

Using **Featherlight** and **JQuery**, I have a lightbox :

> ```
>   <div class="lightbox" id="mylightbox"> Text to display in box </div>
> ```

Instead of using a link, that I do not need, to open it as :

> ```
>   <a  href="#" data-featherlight="#mylightbox">Open element in lightbox</a>
> ```

I would like to trigger it in a javascript function :

> ```
>     $('lightbox.mylightbox').featherlight({
>         });
> ```

I tried with featherlight.click or featherlight.open but it did not work.
Thxs for your help.

---

2nd Edit :
Just found the solution as calling `$('lightbox...` only sets configuration parameters.
I made a forced click on the `<a id="f1" ... >` link through the following javascript function :

> $('f1').click();

Answer (score 10):

[Featherlight](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/) is the lightbox plugin used here. No need to force a click.

#### HTML

```
<div id="mylightbox">Text to display in box</div>
```

#### JS

```
$.featherlight($('#mylightbox'), {});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4nLdswem/)

Comment: How can I do it if I need to open the lightbox using JS, and not based on a DOM element?

Comment: not working with `$.featherlight.defaults.persist = true;`

Answer (score 1):

[@Jacob Raccuia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146158/jacob-raccuia) to open a dynamic content lightbox you still need a DOM placeholder.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#countit').on('click', function() {

    $popup = jQuery('#mylightbox');
    $count = '<div class=numbers>';
    for (var n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
      $count += `<span>${n}</span> `;
    }
    $count += '</div>';
    $popup.html($count);
    jQuery.featherlight($popup, {});

  });

  jQuery('#getit').on('click', function() {
  
    fetch('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=2&start-with-lorem=1')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(function(body) {
        $popup = jQuery('#mylightbox');
        $popup.html(body);
        jQuery.featherlight($popup, {});
      });
      
  });
});
```

```css
#mylightbox {
  display: none;
}

#mylightbox.featherlight-inner {
  display: block;
}

.numbers {
  width: 220px;
}

.numbers span {
  background: #fe0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.7.13/release/featherlight.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.7.13/release/featherlight.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div id="mylightbox"></div>
<button id=getit>Get Bacon</button>
<button id=countit>Count to 100</button>
```